# Ansible replace a string in a variable with a variable

Tags: variables, ansible

```
debug:
  msg: "{{backup_facts | replace(',world',',{{custom}}')}}"
 register: replace_csv
```

in the above code, I am trying to replace a string/word in a variable with a variable.

so in this case these are the vars:

```
backup_facts = "hello,world"
custom = "prab"
```

so the end results I would like is: **"hello, prab"** after the replace. But everytime I run the playbook, I get the following:

```
"replace_csv": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "msg": "hello,{{custom}}"
   }
```

I have attempted different variation such as putting a quotation around the curly brackets  or not putting the curly brackets at all but no results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: ***"The result is: `hello,prab` after the replace."***

[Keep it simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Put the parameters into variables. This will simplify the code. For example,

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    backup_facts: "hello,world"
    custom: "prab"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ backup_facts|replace(old, new) }}"
      vars:
        old: ",world"
        new: ",{{ custom }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: hello,prab
```

Comment: great, that worked. Thank you very much and checked as the solution for it as well.
and moving forward will start using this as it will be easier to read.